# How to data submit and page redirect same position after the button click using javascript python Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, function, fetch

**index.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card shadow-lg">        
        <div class="card-body" id="div1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                        <a href="{% url 'profile' datas.id %}">{{datas.user_id|capfirst}}</a></h5>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-6 text-right" > 
                    {% if request.user.id == datas.user_id_id %}
                         <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"  onclick="load_post(this, '{{datas.id}}')" id="edit">
                         Edit</button>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>              
            <div id="msg">
                    <hr>
                    {{datas.post}}
                    <hr>
            </div>  
            <div id="one">                  
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" value="0" onclick="count(this, '{{datas.id}}')" id="odd"></i><span id="add"></span>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right">{{datas.post_date}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**inbox.js**

```
function load_post(id, data)
{   
const one = id.closest(".card-body");
one.querySelector('#msg').style.display = 'none';    
fetch(`/network/${data}`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(out => {
const element = document.createElement("textarea");
element.classList.add("form-control");
element.rows = 2;
element.id = "body";
element.innerHTML = out["post"];
one.querySelector('#one').appendChild(element);
const li = document.createElement("br");
one.querySelector('#one').appendChild(li);
const button = document.createElement("button");
button.className = "btn btn-sm btn-success"
//button.classList.add("btn"," btn-primary");
button.id="sucees";
button.innerHTML = "SUBMIT";
button.addEventListener('click',() => edited(id, out["id"]));
one.querySelector('#one').appendChild(button);
        })
 }  
function edited(id, data)
{
var two = document.querySelector('#body').value;
    fetch(`/network/${data}`,{
    method : 'POST',
    body : JSON.stringify({
        post : two
    })
})
.then(res=>res.json())
  .then(out=>console.log(out))
 }
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def edit_post(request, post_id):
try:
    post = posts.objects.get(user_id=request.user, pk=post_id)
except posts.DoesNotExist:
    return JsonResponse({"Out":"Data not found"}, status=404)

if request.method == 'GET':
    return JsonResponse(post.serialize())

if request.method == 'POST':
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    upt = data.get("post","")
    post.post = data["post"]
    post.save()
    print(post) 
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

here i am sharing my index.html, inbox.js and views.py files. The user will post the data and after that they will edit thier correspoding post and after that the entire page will not reload it. when I click the submit button, the div element cannot be modified but data posted in the database. after that, I refresh the page the original posted that will appear in the div element. I need help in this regard.